# How can I get separate caches for different coroutines? (Unity)

Tags: unity, coroutines

I want to fade out an image, so I have a coroutine `FadeOut()`. However, I want to have a separate image each time I call FadeOut.

If I try to do something like this:

```
IEnumerator FadeOut(GameObject image) {
    SpriteRenderer render = image.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    yield return null;
}
```

Ignoring all the color changing code which I took out, how do I make it so that I can save a separate cache for each image I add? I don't want to run `GetComponent()` each frame, because I'm running on mobile and because I want to think of a clever way to stash the renderer.

For example, if I declare the renderer at the top like this:

```
private SpriteRenderer render;
```

and want to cache it on the first frame of the coroutine, there's the chance that calling `FadeOut()` on another object will change the renderer to a new object and the first `FadeOut()` will cancel.

Can I make the method static? Will that cache a private version of renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you provided should already be doing what you are asking. If I call `StartCoroutine(FadeOut(image1));` and `StartCoroutine(FadeOut(image2));`, the two coroutines have their own separate `SpriteRenderer renderer;` local references. Unity does not confuse the two. You can continue to fade out image1 even though image2 also started to fade out. That local `renderer` is the renderer specifically for the image that you started the coroutine with.

So, this kind of a code will work just fine. Inside the while loop, `renderer` is the renderer of the image that you initiated this call to the coroutine. You can have many such calls, for every new call, you have a separate local `renderer` variable. They don't affect each other.

```
IEnumerator FadeOut(GameObject image) {
    SpriteRenderer render = image.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    while(!renderer.isDone) {
        renderer.FadeOutOneMoreStep();
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So does a coroutine only repeat the while loop inside? Will this code call GetComponent every frame?

Comment: Yes, only the inside of the loop is repeated.

Comment: And therefore, it won't call GetComponent every frame. Please read "A Practical Description of Coroutines for Game Programmers" down here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932306/how-does-startcoroutine-yield-return-pattern-really-work-in-unity/15412962#15412962